# Determining media format/encoding for DLNA system

Tags: ffmpeg, mplayer, media, video-encoding

How do you determine what parameters are needed by a [DLNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance) renderer and server?

I have a Samsung TV that is a DLNA renderer.  I also have a Western Digital NAS running Debian and have Twonky and MediaTomb 0.12.0 installed.  The Samsung TV seems to have trouble playing some AV formats.  I have tried copying streams with **ffmpeg** to different containers.  In some cases, it seems that the **DLNA Server** affects the ability to play back.  For instance, *Twonky* never seems to allow seeking, where as *MediaTomb* will depending on the AV file; typically only AVI's allow seeking with *MediaTomb/Samsung Tv*.  I don't know whether the render or server is responsible.

In some cases, it appears that *Twonky* will not play files that *MediaTomb* will;  Ie, the **DLNA Server** can give up on a media file.  Most likely the media server gives up parsing/processing the media file; occasionally this has happened mid-stream.

I have *mp4/x264* files that play and many that don't. Is there some suite of programs I can use to analyze the media files to determine how I need to transcode to ensure play back?  I have tried the `midentify.sh` script with **mplayer** and `ffprobe` from **ffmpeg**.  Maybe I haven't turned on enough options?  Mainly some *x264* encoded files have trouble playing.  *Xvid* encoded files never have trouble playing.  Hopefully it is possible to get *MediaTomb* to trancode the files on the fly, but I hope it is not the video stream.  Is there something better than trial/error encodes?  How can I help to zero in on encoding/container parameters that work?

Related:
[What is the difference between DLNA and UPNP?](https://superuser.com/questions/226636/what-is-the-difference-between-dlna-and-upnp)
[Samsung supported formats.](http://i397.photobucket.com/albums/pp60/samsung_hd_tech/Page82.jpg)

**Edit:** Page 34 of the UC6300 user's manual has a list of supported container formats, audio and video codecs, display resolutions and frame and bit rates.

For MP4 and AVI, apparently only 1920x1080 resolutions are supported.  However, I have been able to play many videos at lower resolutions. 6-30fps is supported.  Most encodes are ~24fps so that is not an issue. 8Mbps bit rate for all codecs except H.264BP/MP/HP which lists as 25Mbps (but I think must be 2.5).

AVI/MKV and MP4 supports the following audio codecs,

1. MP3
2. ADPCM
3. AAC (MP4 only)
4. AC3 (AVI/MKV)
5. LCPM (AVI/MKV)
6. DTS core (AVI/MKV)

I typically use *MP3* or *AC3* with the *spdif* pass-thru to an amp.

AVI/MKV/MP4 supports the following video codecs,

1. Divx 3.11/4.x/5.1/6.0 (AVI/MKV)
2. XviD
3. H.264 BP/MP/HP
4. MPEG4 SP/ASP

Additionally, H.264 level 4.1 is supported.  H.264 FMO/ASO/RS, VC1 SP/MP/AP L4 and AVCHD are not supported.  GMC is not supported, H.263 is not supported.  How do I translate this to `midentify.sh` or `ffprobe` output?

Comment: AVI doesn't properly support Main/High Profile H.264.

Comment: I was just posting what the manual says.  It does explicitly list `H.264 BP/MP/HP` for `AVI` and `MKV` containers. Err, you say **properly**, I see. Thanks.

Comment: This particular Samsung TV seems to have problems with the *mkv* container.  Even some *mp4* files give problems.  Usually, an `avconv -i file.mp4 -codec copy file.new.mp4` will make something playable.  Many problems seem to be related to the container as opposed to the streams; I guess `avconv` is not touching the streams with *copy*.